# How do i duplicate a repository using GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api

I am contemplating about the best way to create a new repository that is an exact copy of another repository on GitHub using GitHub API. Downloading and uploading each file seems inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could [create a fork](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/#create-a-fork) of the original repo: that would create a new repo directly on GitHub in your account.

```
POST /repos/:owner/:repo/forks
```

That supposes the original repo isn't already declared in your account.

Comment: This will work, however I would perhaps want to duplicate the same repository more than once, and that does not seems to work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @DekelAdler no, you not doing anything wrong: you can create only one fork per repo.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ruby and the [Octokit library](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb) you could trying somehting like this:

```
# Set Up

class GithubCopy

  def self.copy_repo(args)
    from = args.fetch(:from)
    to   = args.fetch(:to)

    client = Octokit::Client.new(:access_token => 'your access token')

    base_items = client.contents from
    self.copy_items(base_items, from, to, client)
  end

  private

  def self.copy_items(base_items, from, to, client)
    base_items.each do |item|
      content = client.content from, :path => item.path
      if content.is_a?(Array)
        self.copy_items(content, from, to, client)
      else
        client.create_contents to, content.path, "Creating #{content.name}", Base64.decode64(content.content)
      end
    end
  end

end

# Usage
GithubCopy.copy_repo(from: 'repo1', to: 'repo2')
```

This assumes that **repo1** and **repo2** both exist and your access token has appropriate permissions to both repos. If you need to create a repo first use this:

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(:access_token => settings.github_access_token)
client.create_repository 'some-repo', {organization: 'some-org'}
```

If both repos are under the same account you they will require separate names, as @tmarwen stated. One downside is that this approach can take some time depending on the original repo size.